# Why does this program go in endless loop?

Tags: c++

I have such a program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

static int pswd=0;

int main() {

    do {
        std::cout<<"I need your password:"<<std::endl;          
        std::cin>>pswd;
    } while (pswd!=3855);

    std::cout<<"Congratulations! Your password is correct! Your soul is free again!"<<std::endl;
}
```

And I have, may be, a stupid question.
When I enter invalid values (with non-numerical symbols or values greater then int) program goes in endless loop without reading of any information from console.

```
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
I need your password:
        ...
```

Why does this program go in endless loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because after invalid input, the stream is in failed state and all further input operations are no-op. You always have to check the result of the input operation.

```
do {
    std::cout<<"I need your password:"<<std::endl;          
    if (!(std::cin >> pswd)) {
        // clear error flags
        std::cin.clear();
        // discard erroneous input (include <limits>)
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
} while (pswd!=3855);
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to absorb the failed input instead of a `break`

Comment: I didn't really pay attention to the semantics of the loop. It's mostly about illustrating the error handling.

Comment: But this is not the correct way to handle errors - you need to show how to recover from the failed input.

Comment: Fiiiine, I found the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

It is trying to read an `int` but it can take a peek into the buffer from STDIN. It notices that you have not got an `int` so the `cin>>` fails. (See [fail bit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)).

So it just goes around again. You need to check for failed type conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you want to be reading in a string here, as there's nothing to control what the user is typing.

You want to read into a char buffer (the one below supports 256 characters) and then compare it with the password you're looking for using `strcmp`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream.h>

static int pswd=0;
static char buffer[256];

int main()
{
    do
    {
        std::cout<<"I need your password:"<<std::endl;          
        std::cin>>buffer;
    }
    while (strcmp("3855", buffer));
    std::cout<<"Congratulations! Your password is correct! Your soul is free again!"<<std::endl;
}
```

Note that `strcmp` returns 0 when two strings match.

Comment: Thank you. It's a good idea. But I want to understand this phenomena solely in educational purposes.

Comment: This is a potential buffer overflow, use `std::string` instead. Also, the header to include is `<iostream>`.

Comment: That's true enough, hence I pointed out that it only reads 256 characters! But yes, it should use std::string